# Bind dynamic fields in `CSHTML` using `Entity Framework`

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4

I have 2 fields in `Table`. And as per `Stored Procedure's` query, it gives 4 fields. In that, 2 fields are from `Table` and other 2 dynamic fields which I can't mapped in `Entity Framework` directly. So how can I bind that 2 fields in `CSHTML`.

Following is the code I have tried.

**Stored Procedure's Query**

```
SELECT                          
    ROW_NUMBER() Over (Order By Table.Id) SrNo
    ,Id
    ,Name
    ,'10000' Salary
FROM Table
```

**Controller**

```
MyModel model = new MyModel();
SqlParameter param1 = new SqlParameter("@Parameter",1);
model.lstdata = app.Database.SqlQuery<EntityName>("exec ProcedureName @Parameter", param1).ToList();
return View(model);
```

**Model Class**

```
public class Model
{
    public int Id { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<EntityName> lstData { get; set; }
    public Model()
    {
        lstData = new List<EntityName>();
    }
}
```

**CSHTML**

```
@foreach (var item in Model.lstdata)
{
    <tr>     
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SrNo)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Id)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Salary)
        </td>
    </tr>
}
```

**EntityName**

```
namespace Data
{
    [Table("Table")]
    public class EntityName
    {
        [Key]
        public long Id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public int SrNo { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Please suggest me a best option to come out from this query.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. Try adding `[NotMapped]` attribute on the property you don't want to map.

```
public class EntityName
{
    // ...

    [NotMapped]
    public int SrNo { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public int Salary{ get; set; }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: I am getting value '0' in SrNo. But executing query in SQL it gives me a row number well.

Comment: Can you post `EntityName` class?

Answer (score 0):

To bind values in view I would suggest to create separate ViewModelEntity and for database operation use Pure POCO class which has the same fields as in your table.

Comment: Ok but what about 2 dynamic fields. How to bind them??

Comment: Execute stored procedure and map result into viewModelClass(New entity with four fields) so you will get all four fields from that stored procedure and use that class for display purpose in view.

Comment: What if `Stored Procedure` contains dynamic multi queries??

Comment: Or you can do one thing. Create first class class with same fields into table (two fields). Create second viewModelClass (with other two fields). Inherit first class into second class. So now second class will have four fields. Use that second class to map with Stored procedure. And I guess remaining you know